# Notify tag synonyms here

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Tag synonyms are used when

1. there are two different words used to mean the same thing. For e.g., [hydration](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydration) and [watering](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watering) mean the same thing. In this case, the more common word should be made the master tag.
2. the singular form and plural form of the same word is used to tag questions. For e.g., [vegetable](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetable) and [vegetables](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetables). In this case the plural form is preferred to be the master tag (although [lawn](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn) is an exception).
3. there are differences in spellings between U.S. english and U.K. english. For e.g., [zucchini](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zucchini) and [courgette](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/courgette) or [chili](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chili) and [chilli](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chilli). In such cases, the U.S. spelling is preferred and should be made the master.

---

> Use this question to suggest possible tag synonyms so that they can be connected. Instead of leaving multiple answers, **please use the single CW answer below** to add your suggestions.

Answer (score 9):

> Use this answer to suggest synonyms. You can display the tag using markdown as `[tag:example]` which will render as [example](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/example). Also indicate which should be the master. To simplify notation, leave your entries (one on each line) below the separator as:
>
> [synonym](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym) to [master](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master)

---

**SUGGESTIONS:**