# Should tags of nouns be plural or singular?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

**Should tags of nouns be plural or singular?**

Real example: pumpkin vs. pumpkins

If the answer is: "Doesn't Matter", then do we connect the singular and plural versions as [synonyms](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44/notify-tag-synonyms-here)?

Answer (score 9):

Plurals sounds more fitting.

Even if the question mentions the singular, or talks about a single instance, you'll want to group that with other questions on the same topic. And you'll be referring to the plural form to do so.

Read the difference:

- These questions are about [pumpkin](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pumpkin)
- These questions are about [pumpkins](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pumpkins)

The ear and eye just wants to go with the latter.

Answer (score 7):

This was discussed on meta.cooking, here's some of what I've found revisiting it:

> Plural vs. Non Plural
>
> - Plural should have preference unless a collective noun is more
>     appropriate.
> - To make it easier to think about, use the tag in this sentence: "this
>     question is about [tag-name]". It's
>     obvious that "cookies" is better than
>     "cookie". However, it's not so clear
>     that "avocados" is better than
>     "avocado".

https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/511/retagging-recap